# Excel Function 'Application.OnTime' still running after closing the workbook

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am using Excel (Office 365).

here is a video with my problem: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVE_MgBN5-Z4SbwnEsn2cvejTtpKHYgA/view?usp=sharing)

The internet is full of examples where people say that the code should work when we set `Schedule` to `False` but sadly that did not help me.

The code should start a cycle using `Application.OnTime` and stop it before closing the workbook.

- If I run the function `stopF` manually, in the VBA Editor, it stops `Application.OnTime` properly.
- But if I close the workbook, it still opens up and continues executing `Application.OnTime`.

```
' In Module1:

Public startingTime  As Double

Sub startF()
    MsgBox "hello"
    startingTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime startingTime, "Module1.startF"
End Sub

Sub stopF()    'HERE IT WORKS GOOD
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime startingTime, "Module1.startF", , False
End Sub

' In ThisWorkbook:

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Call stopF   'HERE IT DOES NOT WORK GOOD
End Sub
```

I don't have a clue what could I do more.

Comment: Does the code in your `Workbook_BeforeClose` actually run?

Comment: Yes I checked it with a message box in `stopF()` and it was called before closing the workbook, but the rest of the code didn't react.

Comment: Is it possible you managed to create more than one pending `OnTime` calls, and only cancelled the most-recent one?

Comment: The code you can see is the only code in the workbook. I run `startF()` and then experiment with the behaviour. I even put the code from `stopF()` into `Workbook_BeforeClose` but still same behaviour.

Comment: does the `Call stopF` work if you call it from another sub other than `Workbook_BeforeClose`? what i'm thinking is maybe the closing process interrupts it somehow? if you can get `stopF` to work calling from a regular sub then it would mean that the close process *IS* interfering somehow - maybe put a `do while` after the `call stopF` in the `beforeclose` to "slow down" the closing process?

Comment: Weird - I can not reproduce this - you have confirmed that `Workbook_BeforeClose` is being called? I put a debug.print in that function to confirm it is exiting through it and for me it does exit through `Workbook_BeforeClose ` and the stop functions correctly, FWIW

Comment: Yes `Workbook_BeforeClose` is being called. For now the only consclusion I have is that everything works if I manually run it. If I run automatically then not. Example of a tried workaround: I've put `Call stopF` into `Workbook_BeforeSave` and it works if I save manually. If I call in `Workbook_BeforeClose` the function `ThisWorkbook.Save` it again does not work. I will try to make a video of the weird situation and put the link here.

Comment: Here is the screen recording video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVE_MgBN5-Z4SbwnEsn2cvejTtpKHYgA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

**My temporary solution to my question:**

I left the whole code like it was and added into `Module1` following code:

```
' In Module1:

Sub closeWorkbook()
    Call stopF
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The point is:

- for manual closing `stopF` called from `Workbook_BeforeClose` will work
- for vba closing `stopF` called from a `module` will work.

A bit more detailed:

- when a user closes a workbook manually (closes the Excel window) then `Workbook_BeforeClose => Call stopF` will be triggered and it will stop `Application.OnTime` properly.
- if I want to close the workbook via code then I do not rely on the `Workbook_BeforeClose` function (because it doesn't work for this somehow) but I call my new `closeWorkbook()` function when needed, which does terminate `Application.OnTime` and then closes the workbook.